«При всех своих талантах» — нужно ли обособлять?
Нужны ли запятые в этом предложении?
Я, при всех своих талантах, не смогу уже устроить что-то более впечатляющее.

Оборот обособляется:
(1) Я, // при всех своих талантах, // не смогу уже устроить что-то более впечатляющее.
Пояснение

Это несогласованное определение, выраженное падежной формой существительного. Если обороте относится к личному местоимению,то обособляется в обязательном порядке.

С другой стороны, определение можно отнести к сказуемому, и тогда оно не обособляется.

При факультативном обособлении надо учитывать структуру предложения. Оборот находится в позиции между подлежащим и сказуемым, и его желательно обособить.  Делается два ударения, на подлежащем и на обороте.

Без обособления прочтение предложения менее ожидаемо, хотя тоже возможно. Тогда ударение переходит на оборот (одно ударение), при этом он будет интонационно подчеркнут:


(2) Я при всех своих талАнтах / не смогу уже устроить что-то более впечатлЯющее.
Сравнить: Я стоял у кромки озера с опущенным ружьём.
Это дуплексив: несогласованное определение относится к подлежащему "я" и сказуемому "стоял". Нет обособления, трехчастная конструкция.
Розенталь, § 18. Обособленные определения  »»  Несогласованные определения
1. Несогласованные определения, выраженные формами 
косвенных падежей существительных (чаще с 
предлогами), обособляются для выделения какого-либо 
признака или для усиления выражаемого ими 
значения.
...Таким образом, несогласованные 
определения, выраженные формами косвенных падежей 
существительных, обособляются:
3) если относятся к личному местоимению: Я 
удивляюсь, что вы, с вашей добротой, не чувствуете 
этого (Л. Т.); …Сегодня она, в новом голубом 
капоте, была особенно молода (М. Г.);

